# Ace Editor Editing existing mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, ace-editor

i want to edit/update existing ace editor coding language. i want to make curly braces act like block(not comment block) same as begin end; keywords.

i managed to change curly braces. i make them have keyword.control class/token but between curly braces editor still act as comments. how can i fix this this is only the begining i want to change keyword procedure to void so when user write void it will act like procedure.

**I dont want to create new custom mode i want to edit existing one**

[editor demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vltj.png)

Code:
[Code Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10B9y8XSyv7UIANl0Boj_7VIey3eqoPbC/view?usp=sharing)

Rule Object:
[A text file contains rule object](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-sxb_RNcWKQTAFkfGeyYFbYUUGctYOPa/view?usp=sharing)

- Removing comment block for curly braces "{" "}"
- Adding new block keyword: Curly Braces "{" "}"
- Between curly braces shouldn't act like comments
- New keyword should be added "void" will act same as "procedure" keyword

thanks for viewing this post. i really need help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i added code link for users to view already. If they don't want to download they can just see whats in content through link its google drive link.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to, I would recommend borrowing the code from an existing mode into a new one - there's an amount of preprocessing that happens when a mode is loaded so trying to hack into it afterwards doesn't work as well as one might think.